# HttpService not working in<window> in adobe air

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

I am having a windowed application as my base application. To avoid the tab bar icon for the app in the task bar , I close the native window and open up the contents from another window. 
 Here I will be calling the http service method.But nothing happens,and no error is shown in compile and run time.
All the other actions are working fine. why am I not able to call http service within window in adobe air

code in main app to open new window:

```
public function init():void {

                nativeWindow.close();
                    var newWindow:MyWin = new MyWin();
                newWindow.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.NONE;
                newWindow.type = NativeWindowType.LIGHTWEIGHT;
                newWindow.transparent = true;
                newWindow.open(true);   


            }
```

code for window:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Window name="MyWin"
               xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 

               creationComplete="httpService()"   >


        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
                import mx.controls.Alert;
                import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
                import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
                import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;


                public function httpService():void {

                    var httpSer : HTTPService = new HTTPService(); 
                    httpSer.url = "http://flexairapp...";
                    httpSer.method = "GET";
                    httpSer.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, httpResult);
                    httpSer.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, httpFault);
                    httpSer.resultFormat="text";

                    var parameters:Object = new Object(); 
                    httpSer.send();
                }



                public function httpResult(event:ResultEvent):void {


                    var dataResult:String = event.result.toString(); 

                }

                public function httpFault(event:FaultEvent):void {
                    var faultstring:String = event.fault.faultDetail;

                }
            ]]>
        </fx:Script>

    </mx:Window>
```

Comment: Have you run your code in debug mode with breakpoints in httpService, httpResult, and httpFault?  Have you used a network sniffer-such as the Flash Builder Network Monitor--to examine the call to see if you get a response?  Since dataResult and faultString are local variables to the the result and fault handlers; they won't be available outside of the scope of those methods; which could cause unexpected issues depending on what you're trying to do w/ the returned data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your main window visibility to false instead of closing it. I guess it can think that you want to terminate your application (and all child windows of main window are also closed).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ,when I add visible="false" to the WindowedApplication tag, for the main window , its working as expected.